# Azure Functions - Blob Stream Dynamic Input bindings (Imperative binding) for Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function app that is running on Python. I need to have a dynamic input folder to function. To clarify, the input folder is defined in the function.json file like "input/{name}" which means that the function uses all files in the "input" folder as an input. I have read some similar topics for C#.net, but nobody asks about the Python running time.
By googling for a while, I figured out that there is no official solution for Python like C#.net, and I should use [Python SDK for the azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to simulate that. I read the documents, but again I don't know how I should use them.

**function.json:**

```py
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{files}",
      "connection": "parserstoragesa_STORAGE_"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init.py**

```py
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes \n",
                 f"what is this {myfile}"
                 )
```

So I need to define the "path" in a dynamic way.
please help me how I can use Python SDK for azure to solve it (if it is your suggestion)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The content you defined in `function.json` has achieved what you want, you can try to run your function first, and then upload a new blob to your storage, you will find that your function is triggered. Please pay attention to the correct configuration of your `connection`.

Comment: Thank you @FrankGong. But the problem is that the input folder could be from another subscription or storage, right now it just read a different type of files. Also, I want to use an app configuration service to manage it. May I have your contact address if I have an issue? I highly appreciated it.